# Specifying types with TypeScript, when <Array> has different kinds of structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am kind of new to `TypeScript` and I am trying to get rid of all `any` types.

**Problem:**
Within the `React` Component, I loop over an array of objects and extract a `key/value` pair.
The components receives `tags, tagKeys` props as follows:

> `tags: [{ name: "Some tag" }]` OR `[{ platform: { name: "Some tag" } }];`
>
> `tagKeys: ["name"]` OR `tagKeys: ["platform", "name"]`

**If I run this script (below), I get this error in the console:**

> `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'`

```js
type Props = {
    tags: any[];
    tagKeys: string[];
};

const Tags: React.FC<Props> = ({ tags, tagKeys }: PropsWithChildren<Props>) => {
    const renderTags = (): React.ReactNode => {
        return tags.map(tag => {
            let key = "";
            // Loop through tagKeys in the tags array to extract the tag
            for (let i = 0; i < tagKeys.length; i++) {
                key = i === 0 ? tag[tagKeys[i]] : key[tagKeys[i]];
            }
            return <Tag key={`tag-${key}`} tag={key} />;
        });
    };
    return <StyledTags>{renderTags()}</StyledTags>;
};
```

If I change the line inside the for loop to...

> `key = i === 0 ? tag[tagKeys[i] as any] : key[tagKeys[i] as any];`

...the script runs but I want to get rid of the `any` type.

**Question:**
Is there a way to set the type without specifying how the received `props` array `tags` will look?

I want to be able to pass arrays with different kinds of structure and extract a key/value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` can be either a string or an object during it's lifetime, so my first intuition would be to declare it as such:

```
let key: object | string = "";
```

But TS is not happy with that, so my second try would be:

```
type NestedObject = { [key: string]: NestedObject } | string
let key: NestedObject = '';

key = { platform: { name: 'dd' } }
key = key.platform.name
```

But TS is not happy with the last line either, so at this time I would just give up:

```
let key: any = '';
```

Comment: You are correct in that key will be either a string or an object. But declaring it as that will give me the error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'string | object'."

Comment: Yes, it's true. Because in `TypeScript`, once you know beforehand that a variable will take on more than one `type`. It's then advised to explicitly declare it as `any` type.

Comment: ah, well... looks like the recursive data structure is not TS friendly, so indeed I would use `any` here as well after 1 more attempt to be clever :)

Comment: @MwamiTovi I wouldn't say it were advisable "beforehand", only when not possible to use a simple union type and you are not a library author who should try really hard to find a clever trick with generics (`<T>`) for the benefit of their users

Comment: @Aprillion i only stated it that way since our colleague knew "beforehand" that the variable `key` would mutate throughout this process. And indeed, you are right too, am not one of the library authors.

Answer (score 3):

There two issues to watch that we'll need to be clear about.

- **First**, you asked:
  Is there a way to set the type without specifying how the received props array tags will look?

```js
type Props = {
    tags: any[]; // This is the answer to your direct question
    tagKeys: string[];
};
```

- **Secondly**, having handled the above, `TypeScript` is actually complaining about your `index`.
  As you'll agree, `reactjs` uses the unique `key` to render each `<Tag>`.

```js
// TypeScript is actually warning you about this.

// Note that initially, `key` is of type `string` (implicitly or indirectly )
let key = "";

// Within your loop, you assign `key` to be of type `object`
key = i === 0 ? tag[tagKeys[i]] : key[tagKeys[i]];
// So the above line says that `key` can be `string` or `object`
// Thus TypeScript tells you that...
// implicitly your index (key) expression is of type any
```

To handle that `TypeScript` error, update as follows:

```js
let key: any = "";
```

Kindly make the necessary updates, and let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: let key: number or let key will not work as I will get "Variable 'key' is used before being assigned." Also key is never a number as far as i can understand. Its a object if it has not reached the last tagKey, when it has reached the last tagKey its a string.

Comment: Oh, alright. In that case, it means that the variable `key` is an `object`, a `number` (because you re-assign it as `key = i ===...`) and finally a `string` (because of `let key = ""`). Kindly see my updated answer.

Comment: it's never a `number`... the ternary operator `? :`  will never evaluate to the first operand (the condition)... and even if it could, `i === 0` is a boolean, not a number

Comment: When we carefully analyze this line, `key = i === 0 ? ... : ...`. Notice that the user first re-assigns `key` in other words, `key = i`. And then gets into the `ternary` operator. @Aprillion, if this was not the case then `let key: object | string = ""` would have worked. But unfortunately, in this case you are dealing with a variable that mutates through 3 `types`. Therefore, we can't use a simple union.

Comment: no, it doesn't. assignment evaluates the right-hand side value first, before updating where the left-hand side variable (or object property) points to. see [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), almost everything is evaluated before the assignment operator

Comment: Yes, @Aprillion you are right, actually. `key` is re-assigned to the result of the ternary operator. Thanks for that clarification.

Comment: the reason of the any is from `tags: any[]` => `tag: any` => `tag[whatever]: any`